# How to resize an UIImage while maintaining its Aspect Ratio

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uikit

I want to resize a `UIImage` with maintaining its Aspect Ratio. I have written the following code, but it is not working as expected.

**Code**

```
-(UIImage * ) scaleImage: (UIImage * ) image toSize: (CGSize) targetSize {

    CGFloat scaleFactor = 1.0;
    if (image.size.width > targetSize.width || image.size.height > targetSize.height)
        if (!((scaleFactor = (targetSize.width / image.size.width)) > (targetSize.height / image.size.height))) //scale to fit width, or
            scaleFactor = targetSize.height / image.size.height; // scale to fit heigth.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake((targetSize.width - image.size.width * scaleFactor) / 2, (targetSize.height - image.size.height * scaleFactor) / 2,
        image.size.width * scaleFactor, image.size.height * scaleFactor);
    [image drawInRect: rect];
    UIImage * scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return scaledImage;
}
```

What exactly is wrong here?

Answer (score 41):

I'm using something similar to this in a few projects:

```
- (UIImage*) scaleImage:(UIImage*)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    CGSize scaledSize = newSize;
    float scaleFactor = 1.0;
    if( image.size.width > image.size.height ) {
        scaleFactor = image.size.width / image.size.height;
        scaledSize.width = newSize.width;
        scaledSize.height = newSize.height / scaleFactor;
    }
    else {
        scaleFactor = image.size.height / image.size.width;
        scaledSize.height = newSize.height;
        scaledSize.width = newSize.width / scaleFactor;
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( scaledSize, NO, 0.0 );
    CGRect scaledImageRect = CGRectMake( 0.0, 0.0, scaledSize.width, scaledSize.height );
    [image drawInRect:scaledImageRect];
    UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

    return scaledImage;
}
```

Comment: That looks pretty similar to whats in my projects as well, ^1.

Comment: This skewed my images , but UIImage+FX from github https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXImageView does aspect fill

Comment: What should the content mode be set to when using this?

Comment: I can't believe this has so many upvotes. It's totally buggy. The question is to maintain aspect ratio. let's say we're scaling an image where size is 100x1 to a size of 1x100.  We go into the "if" statement because width > height. scaleFactor = 100 / 1 = 100. scaledSize.width = 1. scaledSize.height = 100 / 100 = 1. Output size is 1x1 which is a very different aspect ratio than the input image size of 100x1.

Comment: This algorithm is flawed, as noticed by @KyleRobson. A better algo can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38062640/1033581

Answer (score 23):

If this is for displaying in a UI, you can use Interface Builder and specify the "Aspect Fit" property.

You can also do this in code by setting the content mode to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Answer (score 10):

This method takes an image and a max dimension. If the max original image dimension is less than the specified max dimension, you get the original back so it won't get blown up. Otherwise, you get a new image having a max dimension of the one specified and the other determined by the original aspect ratio. So as an example, if you give it a 1024x768 image and max dimension of 640 you get back a 640x480 version, if you give it a 768x1024 image and max dimension of 640 you get back a 480x640 version.

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image
        withMaxDimension:(CGFloat)maxDimension
{
    if (fmax(image.size.width, image.size.height) <= maxDimension) {
        return image;
    }

    CGFloat aspect = image.size.width / image.size.height;
    CGSize newSize;

    if (image.size.width > image.size.height) {
        newSize = CGSizeMake(maxDimension, maxDimension / aspect);
    } else {
        newSize = CGSizeMake(maxDimension * aspect, maxDimension);
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 1.0);
    CGRect newImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, newSize.width, newSize.height);
    [image drawInRect:newImageRect];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... just what i needed

Comment: Can this be used to get 16:9?

Answer (score 5):

In my case (I wanted to have an image in a UIView) and keep the ratio with auto layout the way described [here](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/auto-layout-in-ios-6-keep-aspect-ratio-of-image) was great. The most important part of the article for me was (almost quoting):

```
constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.imageView
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                             toItem:self.imageView 
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth 
                                         multiplier:ration 
                                           constant:0.0f];

[self.imageView addConstraint:constraint];
```

the only thing is to calculate the ratio according to the actual width and height of image. I found this way easy and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    float ratio = newSize.width/image.size.width;
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, ratio * image.size.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    NSLog(@"New Image Size : (%f, %f)", newImage.size.width, newImage.size.height);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 5** you can use `scaleAspectFit` on the `contentMode` attribute.

```
let photo = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "your_img_name")
let photoImageView = UIImageView(image: photo)     
        
photoImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```