# How to resize AsyncImageView (subclass of UIImageView) while maintaining its Aspect Ratio

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

I have used the below code from this link:
[How to resize an UIImage while maintaining its Aspect Ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703502/how-to-resize-an-uiimage-while-maintaining-its-aspect-ratio)
to resize an image to fixed size (100*100) by maintaing its aspect ratio. I have used **AsyncImageView** in my application to load the images using url's. You can get the **AsyncImageView** code from this link:  [nicklockwood / AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView)

But still those images looks like squeezed. How can I solve this issue?

```
- (UIImage*) scaleImage:(UIImage*)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    CGSize scaledSize = newSize;
    float scaleFactor = 1.0;
    if( image.size.width > image.size.height ) {
        scaleFactor = image.size.width / image.size.height;
        scaledSize.width = newSize.width;
        scaledSize.height = newSize.height / scaleFactor;
    }
    else {
        scaleFactor = image.size.height / image.size.width;
        scaledSize.height = newSize.height;
        scaledSize.width = newSize.width / scaleFactor;
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( scaledSize, NO, 0.0 );
    CGRect scaledImageRect = CGRectMake( 0.0, 0.0, scaledSize.width, scaledSize.height );
    [image drawInRect:scaledImageRect];
    UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

    return scaledImage;
}
```

This is how the images are being loaded in my application:
[image]

Comment: small correction asyncImageView is not an imageView it is a UIView

Comment: No it is not. @interface AsyncImageView : UIImageView

Comment: sorry my mistake. I was using UIView version

Comment: Please try this on your AsyncImageView instance `imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`

Comment: I have already given that too .. still the images are not scaled properly.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use SDWebImage to get remote image?
Here is the link:https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage