# Crop off parts of UIImage for new aspect ratio and scale down to size

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am capturing an image with the UIImagePickerController, and I use the cameraViewTransform to make it full screen on iPhone 5 so there's no black boxes on the top or bottom.

```
self.imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.7125, 1.7125);
```

When the user takes the photo, this returns an image that is 2448 x 3264 pixels. This is a 1.333 ratio, I need to crop off the sides to make it 1906 x 3264 pixels to fit in my view at a new aspect ratio, and then I want to scale it down to 320 x 548 pixels to make it full screen on the iPhone 5 (but not gigantic).

How is this achieved?

Comment: Did you ever get this solved??

Comment: how did you end up implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703502/how-to-resize-an-uiimage-while-maintaining-its-aspect-ratio?rq=1).  You'll want to add scaling and be cognizant of the order of your operations.