# UIImage doesn't want to fit in my Slide Show

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiimage

In order to make a Slide Show, I installed the KASlideShow pod, which is perfect. On the iphone 5S, my Slideshow took all the width (What I wanted), but, when it comes to test the app on the iPhone 6, it takes only 3/4 of the screen.

I tried to scale the UIImage using this method :

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0, width, height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( rect.size );
[originialImage drawInRect:rect];
UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(finalImage);
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

But it only scales to 3/4, even if I put enormous values. It's as if there was a limit.
I tried to use `UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill` attribute, but it doesn't do anything.
I do not have more ideas to test :/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you change `UIImageView` accordingly?

Comment: Well, I do not work with UIImageView objects. I use a method of KASlideShow (addImage) that takes a UIImage as parameter

Comment: Internally `KASlideShow` handles `UIImageView` because without imageView you can not use image directly. Check this library.

Comment: I know we need `UIImageView` to display the data of a UIImage, the problem is not in the display, I know how to scale images, (the code above do it) but, I cannot scale more than something like 300px

Comment: May be this will help you -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703502/how-to-resize-an-uiimage-while-maintaining-its-aspect-ratio

Comment: Well, after doing lots of tests, I found what is the real problem : The SlideShow's images doesn't respect constraints. If you design it for a 5S, it will work on the 5S but not on the 6. I tried to design for the iPad using constraints (that work for other uI elements of the page), it doesn't work on the iPhone 6 and below (Image cropped)

Comment: You can contact to the `KASlideShow` library developer or if it is a git repo than put an issue in Git.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I'm going to do ! Thanks for your attention :)