# How to scale an image down in iOS Share Extension before uploading

Tags: ios, memory-management, uigraphicscontext, ios8-share-extension, memory-pressure

I am building a share extension and I need to scale large photos to a smaller size before uploading in my share extension.

I'm using this code from [How to resize an UIImage while maintaining its Aspect Ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703502/how-to-resize-an-uiimage-while-maintaining-its-aspect-ratio):

```
- (UIImage*) scaleImage:(UIImage*)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    CGSize scaledSize = newSize;
    float scaleFactor = 1.0;
    if( image.size.width > image.size.height ) {
        scaleFactor = image.size.width / image.size.height;
        scaledSize.width = newSize.width;
        scaledSize.height = newSize.height / scaleFactor;
    }
    else {
        scaleFactor = image.size.height / image.size.width;
        scaledSize.height = newSize.height;
        scaledSize.width = newSize.width / scaleFactor;
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( scaledSize, NO, 0.0 );
    CGRect scaledImageRect = CGRectMake( 0.0, 0.0, scaledSize.width, scaledSize.height );
    [image drawInRect:scaledImageRect];
    UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return scaledImage;
}
```

However, when I'm trying to scale down a large image from my photos library (5415x3610 in this case, shot with a DSLR) it crashes due to memory pressure. While it seems like a corner case, my app depends highly on iOS Share Extension to share photos from non-iPhone sources like a high-resolution photo from a camera.

Obviously, uploading a 20MP/8MB photo without scaling down is not an option. How can I scale it down with less memory use?

Comment: Unless your newSize is a square, there is an algorithm issue: you're only looking at original ratio `if( image.size.width > image.size.height )` and not at target ratio (`newSize.width / newSize.height`), so you're potentially increasing the width or height. The source of this code should be fixed or downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem like you. The scale down operation was increasing my memory usage by +800MB and at times the app crashed because of memory usage. What worked for me was replacing `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` with the new ios 10 `UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat`. Here's my swift code of performing image scaling:

```
extension UIImage {
    func scaled(to size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.scale = scale
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: format)
        return renderer.image { (_) in
            draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your image and scaledImage are in memory at once, which both images could be using to much. You could try to release your image before creating your scaledImage:

```
//code

[image drawInRect:scaledImageRect];
image = nil;
UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//code
```